# Select matches beginning numbers of string on integer

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `text` varchar(250) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Content:

```
ID     text  
1      70-and-some-text  
70     blub
```

Then I make execute this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test
WHERE
    ID = '70-and-some-text'
OR
    text = '70-and-some-text'
```

and get both lines as a result. It seems that MySQL tries to match as many numbers against ID and then stops. I think I read that somewhere, but couldn't find it anymore.

Answer and hints are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. And be kind, I'm new. Tell me, if I did something wrong. I have a lot of respect for you guys.

Steffen

==================

Thanks to Tomalak, I know now where the problem comes from. Any best practices for dealing with this? I control the 'text', so I could go for '_70-and-some-text' or the the string with PHP. But a solution in MySQL would be the "purest".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line

```
ID = '70-and-some-text'
```

makes MySQL convert the right-hand-side operand to an INT, since the column is of type INT. conversion obviously results in the number 70. You can pass any data type into a MySQL query in form of a string, MySQL does the necessary type-conversion transparently, like in this case.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I can't point out to if this behavior is described anywhere in the MySQL documentation but it boils down to the following.

MySQL tries to interpret any data sent to a number column (e.g. int, decimal) as a number, no matter if it makes sense or not to do so. Even a date could be interpreted as number or if MySQL isn't able to make out anything useful of the data passed along it simply stores 0.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (intcolumn) VALUES (NOW()); //2009
INSERT INTO yourtable (intcolumn) VALUES ('aa'); //0
INSERT INTO yourtable (intcolumn) VALUES (12.12); //12
INSERT INTO yourtable (intcolumn) VALUES (12.8); //13 (!)
.....
```

I guess this behavior could be turned of by using the right [MySQL Server Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html)